# How are PvP servers different?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

My guild has joined a PvP server, and I'm not really a PvP player. I'm wondering how does PvP work? Will I get ganked whilst out and about?

Will I lose all my items when I'm killed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [swtorstrategyguide.net's "Server Types"](http://www.swtorstrategyguide.net/swtor-server-types/) article:

- PvP servers are ideal for players who want to battle the other faction.
- PvE servers are ideal for players who want to play cooperative games with their own faction.
- RP servers are for people who prefer to act in character. There are usually only a few RP servers all together in an MMORPG, so if you do not know what role-playing is, this is likely not for you.

And my addition:

- RP-PvP servers combine the two.

No, you do not lose any items when killed.

There is a feature called item damage, but you shouldn't have to worry about it — in regards to PvP anyway. Let me explain: Usually if you die a lot, your character's equipped armor/items need repaired from time to time to keep functioning. Most vendors let your repair damaged equipment for the price of a few credits; the higher level the equipment the more credits. *But* PvP deaths do not affect this in SWTOR.

The only real issue you have with PvP servers is having to stay vigilant when questing in contested (non-faction specific) zones (level 20+ areas usually) so that you aren't killed over and over while trying to do other things. But if you have help, like your guild for instance, you can call in your friends as backup if someone is griefing you.

There should be no monetary cost to your character on a PvP server. In the worst case, only your time respawning or running back to where you were when you were killed. And even then, SWTOR let's you respawn exactly where you die, though there is a timer on that feature.

Answer (score 2):

PvP will not cause you to lose your items.

You will get ganked whist out and about in contested areas, but generally you won't encounter those planets/star systems until around level 20.

PvP battlegrounds will also ramp up your health and damage, but in the world you won't have those enhancements so you will die a little easier in world PvP.

Comment: So I'm not going to get ganked whilst running around Corascent then? I'm glad!